# Is there design pattern to update hundreds of attributes of a Java class?

Tags: java, design-patterns

We have a use case where there is a class that has more than 130 attributes. There is a method that populates all the attributes and it is just very long just because of large number of attributes. Just the setters would make the method very long.

Just to give context about the source for these attributes, these are populated by different datasources. Few of them are from different micro services and few of them are from a mysql tables.

Our current solution is to group them into different groups based on the source or some similar business trait and update them in different methods. This has made some of the setters in different methods and just makes it very hard to read.

I have read else where about the builder pattern. But most of these attributes need some transformation after fetching from source and assigning each of the attributes to a temp variables and using them in the builder doesn't help much.

Comment: The problem is the class that has more than 130 attributes.  Why does it have this many? There is almost 0 chance than this is being accurately modeled.  At the very  least it can be broken into groups of attributes and each group be an updatable object.

Comment: I have to wonder if the question is an XY problem, if the best solution is to refractor so that your class has far fewer attributes

Comment: It seems very unlikely that your business logic needs to update all 130 fields with no possible breakdowns. Load only the bare minimum of what you need for various computations. If the result of your computation is meant to enrich the initial large datamodel, try to use a system of ID to trace which result goes with which input, if applicable. We have very little information here so it's difficult to not be very vague.

Answer (score 0):

*"Is there a design pattern...?"* Nope.

First and foremost, reconsider whether this object even needs that many fields. *"Our current solution is to group them into different groups"* this suggests it doesn't.

If it genuinely needs that many fields and if the fields are identically named on both the source and target objects, i.e. the main instance with 130 fields is basically a composite of all the others, then you could consider using reflection.

e.g.  for the following value objects

```
class Main {
    private String a;
    private Number b;
    private String c;
    private String d;
}
class A {
    private final String a;

    A(String a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
}
class B {
    private final Integer b;

    B(Integer b) { this.b = b; }
}
class C {
    private final String c;

    C(String c) { this.c = c; }
}
```

A simple example would be

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Main main = new Main();

    A a = new A("a1");
    B b = new B(2);
    C c = new C("c3");

    // Get all values from all sources
    Map<String, Object> fieldToValue = new HashMap<>();
    Stream.of(a, b, c).forEach(obj -> {
        Field[] fields = getFieldsForInstance(obj);
        for (Field field : fields) {
            try {
                Object prevValue = fieldToValue.put(field.getName(), field.get(obj));
                if (prevValue != null) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Duplicate source field " + field.getName());
                }
            }
            catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    });

    // Set the values on main instance
    Field[] mainFields = getFieldsForInstance(main);
    for (Field field : mainFields) {
        if (fieldToValue.containsKey(field.getName())) {
            Object value = fieldToValue.get(field.getName());
            if (value != null) {
                if (field.getType().isAssignableFrom(value.getClass())) {
                    field.set(main, value);
                }
                else {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Incompatible types for field " + field.getName());
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("warning: field " + field.getName() + " is unset on main");
        }
    }
}

private static Field[] getFieldsForInstance(Object obj) {
    Field[] fields = obj.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
    for (Field field : fields) {
        field.setAccessible(true);
    }
    return fields;
}
```

I'd also consider whether you could use code generation at compile time, e.g. JavaPoet.